# Calculation about the process of Ricci flow induced by soliton

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In page 2 of *[An optimal volume growth estimate for noncollapsed steady gradient Ricci solitons](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.04661v2.pdf)*, the authors say the blow result.

---

Assum $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold,   $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a function,
$k$ is a constant,
$\Phi_t:M\rightarrow M$ are  diffeomorphisms. If
\begin{align}
& \partial_t \Phi_t = \frac{1}{1-kt}\nabla f \circ \Phi_t   \\
& \Phi_0= id   \\
& g_t = (1-kt)\Phi_t^* g
\end{align}
and $g$ satisfy
$$
Ric +\nabla^2 f = \frac{k}{2}g
$$
then **$g_t$ moves by Ricci flow**.

---

I want to verify **it**. But, I don't know how to use
$$
 \partial_t \Phi_t = \frac{1}{1-kt}\nabla f \circ \Phi_t
$$
to calculate
$$
\partial_t [\Phi_t^* g].
$$

---

After Dider's hint, (although I don't know why $\partial_t$ and $d$ commute)I get
$$
\partial_t[\Phi_t^* g]= 2g_{\Phi_t}(d\partial_t\Phi_t\cdot,d\Phi_t\cdot) \\
=
2g_{\Phi_t}(d[\frac{1}{1-kt}\nabla f\circ \Phi_t]\cdot,d\Phi_t\cdot)  \\
=
2\frac{1}{1-kt}d(\nabla f)  g_{\Phi_t}(d\Phi_t \cdot,d\Phi_t\cdot)  \\
=2\frac{1}{1-kt}d(\nabla f) \Phi_t^* g
$$
Therefore
$$
\partial_t g_t  =\Phi_t^*(-kg+ 2d(\nabla f)g)
$$
I guess $d(\nabla f)g=\nabla^2 f$, but don't know why. In fact, I don't know what is the differentiation of a vector field.

Besides, why the $\Phi_t$ of  $g_{\Phi_t}$ needn't to be $\partial_t$ ? (If need, I don't know how to calculate it.)

Comment: $\Phi_t^*g$ is just a compact notation for $g_{\Phi_t}(d\Phi_t\cdot,d\Phi_t\cdot)$. Use the fact that $g$ is time-independent and that $\partial_t$ and $d$ commute

Comment: @Didier  Thanks for your help. With your hint,  I still have some problem, and add it in above problem. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: $\partial_t$ acts by the Lie derivative $L_{\partial_t}$ on tensors, and it is a well-known fact that the exterior differential and the Lie derivative in the direction of any vector fields commute on differential forms

Comment: Also: you cannot apply $d$ to a vector field since it is not a differential form

Comment: Forget about my first comment: think of $\partial_t \Phi_t$ as the tangent vector to the curve $t\mapsto \Phi_t(x)$. This is what is meant by $\partial_t\Phi_t = \nabla f\circ \Phi_t$.

Comment: @Didier  I know the both sides of $g_t = (1-kt)\Phi_t^* g$ are vector. But I still don't know how to get $g_t$ moves by Ricci flow.

Comment: No they are not, they are symmetric 2-tensors

Comment: @Didier   i copy wrong. both sides of $\partial_t \Phi_t = \frac{1}{1-kt}\nabla f \circ \Phi_t$  are vector.